# Alamofire handle bool response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I use Alamofire in my app to work with network request, along with Object Mapper. It's fine when i have JSON response, but now i need to handle response that simply return 200 as status code, and value is `true`.

I have no idea how to map it to Swift Bool value, i simply have `Data?` in response, and i can't figure out how to transform it to Swift `Bool` type.

So, i only have `Alamofire` `public struct DataResponse<Value> {...}` as response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `responseJSON` instead and cast the response value to `Bool`?

```
if let myBool = response.value as? Bool {
...
}
```

Comment: It always fail because you try to convert Data to Bool

Comment: I can't verify this at the moment, but doesn't responseJSON return an Any which can then be cast to Bool?

Comment: in my case it is public struct DataResponse<Value> {...} that is described in Alamofire, and it's associated value is always Data?

Comment: But you don't HAVE to use that one. Use responseJSON instead: AF.request([url]).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by following - cast `Data` to `String`, then try to form `Bool` from raw string value.

```
.request(request: apiRequest,
               completionSuccess: { response  in
                guard let data = response.value,
                      let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
                      let resultValue = str.toBool() else {
                        completion(.failure(APIError.emptyData))
                        return
                }
                completion(Result.success(resultValue))
```

String extension:

```
extension String {
  func toBool() -> Bool?{
    if self == "true" {
      return true
    }
    if self == "false" {
      return false
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```